# get data success but ng-repeat not showing

Tags: angularjs

Here is my code

Services

```
            function dataServices($http,$stateParams){
                     var services ={
                       getCate:getCate
                      };
               return services
}

    function getCate(){
                        return $http({
                            method:'GET',
                            url:'/saha/src/server/action/getcate.php?id=' +$stateParams.id,
                            data:{
                                'id' :$stateParams.id
                            },
                            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

                        }).then(getCateComplete)
                          .catch(function(message){
                             exception.catcher('XHR Failed for getCate')(message)
                          });

                          function getCateComplete(data,status,headers,config){
                            return data.data
                          }
                    }
```

Controller

```
    function cateController(dataServices){
                var vm = this;
                vm.cate = dataServices.getCate();
}
```

Here is data i get in console.log
[image]

Code i display in html

```
<ul ng-repeat ="data in vm.cate">
    <li>{{data.masp}}</li>
</ul>
```

But nothing showing . Where is my wrong ? Pls help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you can't bind promise directly in view. Try as follows.

```
 function cateController(dataServices){
    var vm = this;
    var promise = dataServices.getCate();
    promise.then(getCateComplete)
            .catch(function(message){
                 exception.catcher('XHR Failed for getCate')(message)
             });

    function getCateComplete(data,status,headers,config){
       vm.cate = data.data;
    }
 }
```

In service file,

```
 function getCate(){
    return $http({
       method:'GET',
       url:'/saha/src/server/action/getcate.php?id=' +$stateParams.id,
       headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    });
 }
```

Comment: Thank so much , it work perfect . Can you explain for me why I can't bind promise directly in view

Comment: HTTP Promise is asynchronous. It doesn't return anything. We can get data in success callback only. So, we have use call back in controller file.

Answer (score 0):

Try `data[0].masp` once and if you can see the value then you will have to loop over the data, because I think its an array. Not the actual object you are expecting.